# CTypes error in return value

Tags: python, assembly, dll, nasm, x86-64

I'm testing a very simple NASM dll (64-bit) called from ctypes.  I pass a single int_64 and the function is expected to return a different int_64.

I get the same error every time:

```
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000000000092A
```

where hex value translates to the value I am returning (in this case, 2346).  If I change that value, the hex value changes to that value, so the problem is in the value I am returning in rax.  I get the same error if I assign mov rax,2346.

I have tested this repeatedly, trying different things, and I've done a lot of research, but this seemingly simple problem is still not solved.

Here is the Python code:

```
def lcm_ctypes():

    input_value = ctypes.c_int64(235)

     hDLL = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:/NASM_Test_Projects/While_Loop_01/While_loops-01.dll")

    CallTest = hDLL.lcm
    CallTest.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int64]
    CallTest.restype = ctypes.c_int64

    retvar = CallTest (input_value)
```

Here is the NASM code:

```
[BITS 64]

export lcm

section .data
return_val: dq 2346

section .text
finit

lcm:
push rdi
push rbp
mov rax,qword[return_val]
pop rbp
pop rdi
```

Thanks for any information to help solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe because your function is missing `ret`?

Comment: By the way that `finit` is doing nothing. It is outside of the function, and you aren't using the x87 FPU related instructions. it can be eliminated.

Comment: I also recommend you find a tutorial about debugging python and a DLL. There are a number of such tutorials using Visual Studio (even the free version will suffice). You can set a breakpoint at the function entry point and have it stop there. this allows you to step through the instructions to see why things are failing.

Comment: I recommend getting the function to work by calling it from C before trying to make it work with ctypes.  The problem isn't a `ctypes` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function correctly loads `2346` (`0x92a`) into RAX.  **Then execution continues into some following bytes because you didn't `jmp` or `ret`.**

In this case, we can deduce that the following bytes are probably `00 00`, which decodes as `add byte [rax], al`, hence the `access violation writing 0x000000000000092A` error message.  (i.e. it's not a coincidence that the address it's complaining about is your constant).

As Michael Petch said, using a debugger would have found the problem.

You also don't need to save/restore `rdi` because you're not touching it.  The Windows x86-64 calling convention has many call-clobbered registers, so for a least-common-multiple function you shouldn't need to save/restore anything, just use rax, rcx, rdx, r8, r9, and whatever else Windows lets you clobber (I forget, check the calling convention docs in the [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info), especially Agner Fog's guide).

---

You should definitely use `default rel` at the top of your file, so the `[return_val]` load will use a RIP-relative addressing mode instead of absolute.

---

**Also, `finit` never executes because it's *before* your function label.**  But you don't need it either.  You had the same `finit` in your previous asm question: [Passing arrays to NASM DLL, pointer value gets reset to zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48373312/passing-arrays-to-nasm-dll-pointer-value-gets-reset-to-zero), where it was also not needed and not executed.  The calling convention requires that on function entry (and return), the x87 FPU is already in the state that `finit` puts it in, more or less.  So you don't need it before executing x87 instructions like `fmulp` and `fidivr`.  But you weren't doing that anyway, you were using SSE FP instructions (which is recommended, especially in 64-bit mode), which don't touch the x87 state at all.

Go read a good tutorial and some docs (some links in the x86 tag wiki) so you understand what's going on well enough to debug a problem like this on your own, or you will have a bad time writing anything more complicated.  Guessing what might work doesn't work very well for asm.

From a deleted non-answer: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2017/fall/cs301/reference/nasm_vs/ shows how to set up Visual Studio to build an executable out of C++ and NASM sources, so you can debug it.